# EF Core 2: Problem with creating mapping with deletebehaviour.Restrict

Tags: ef-code-first, ef-core-2.0

I have the following two tables:

-Table1 (Principal)
-Table2

Entities:

```
public partial class Table2
{
     public int Table2Id{ get; set; }
     public int Tabl1Id{ get; set; }   

     public virtual Table1 Table1 { get; set; }
}


public partial class Table1  
{        
    public virtual ICollection<Table2> Table2Items { get; set; }           
}
```

For this I create the following mapping:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Table2>()
                .HasOne(e => e.Table1 )
                .WithMany(e => e.Table2Items)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.Table1Id)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

This gives me the following piece of code in the migration file:

```
migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Table2_Table1_Table1Id",
                table: "Table2",
                column: "Table1Id",
                principalTable: "Table1",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

How come that my migration is still resolving the cascade behaviour for this relationship?

Comment: `.WithMany()` should be `.WithMany(e => e.Table2Items)`. Currently you are creating **two** one-to-many relationships.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Not the problem, but you are correct! Thank you, I fixed this

Comment: Well, if that's the exact fluent code, no other hidden code (like reflection/model loops etc.) and the migration is regenerated, it should give you `Restrict`. It can easily be proved by a clean project containing just the code from the post.